# Svelte suscriptions to GraphQL

Tags: neo4j, graphql, svelte

Is there a 'svelte idiomatic' way to subscribe via GraphQL to a datastore.  I see there are various stacks involving Sapper, Apollo, etc.  I was hoping for something minimalist, and svelte centric.  The datastore I am working with is Neo4j, and most likely it will have a 1:1 mapping with objects defined in GraphQL.

Comment: I suggest Sapper URQL - https://github.com/jdgamble555/sapper-urql-ssr